# Does setting optimization to none (-O0) also disable garbage collection?

Tags: gcc

I was looking at my .lss file and noticed that a block of strings from a header file were being included in the final binary even though they were not used or referenced by anything.  I had included the various compiler/linker garbage collection flags (-ffunction-sections, -fdata-sections, -Wl,--gc-sections) but was compiling with optimization set to -O0.

Does using this level of optimization override the garbage collection, disabling it?  Am I misunderstanding that gc should remove these strings?

To verify that the strings were not actually used, I commented out the whole block and it rebuilt without issue.  Interestingly, doing this removed over 30k from the final binary size despite this being less than 2k of strings.  So it looks like not only were the unused strings being included, they were being included multiple times over.

Leaving the strings uncommented and switching from -O0 to -O1 removed them from the .lss and final binary as expected (along with performing many other optimizations).

I like to build with -O0 while developing, but I'm pushing the limits of my flash size due to this.

Comment: Are you building an executable or a library? Could you create a minimal example (it should only require a couple functions)? --gc-sections works even if the object files are produced by gcc -O0.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Executable, but in the form of a flash binary for an embedded ARM processor. 

The text in question is implemented as a static const array of this struct
struct bit_2_string {
  uint8_t bit;
  char *string;
};

so:
static const struct bit_2_string REASON[50] = ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the answer:

> -fkeep-static-consts
>
> Emit variables declared static const when optimization isn't turned
> on, even if the variables aren't referenced.
>
> GCC enables this option by default. If you want to force the compiler
> to check if a variable is referenced, regardless of whether or not
> optimization is turned on, use the -fno-keep-static-consts option.

Comment: It's fairly common to use a `static` object for things like version identifiers, which you want to have embedded in the binary even though the code doesn't use it.  So that's probably why this is enabled by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).